# "as much as" or "as many as" forty degrees?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, countable-nouns, countability

> "the temperature can vary by **as much as** forty degrees"

this sentence confused me, following *as much as*, there is plural word (forty degrees) but it was used with "as much as". Because there is a plural word, isn't it necessary that we use "as many as"?

English is not my mother tongue, excuse my poor English.

Comment: Native speakers aren't that pedantic. We'd nearly always say some imprecisely-known distance might be [*as **much** as two inches*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+much+as+two+inches%2Cas+many+as+two+inches&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20much%20as%20two%20inches%3B%2Cc0) (not *...as **many** as two...*), for example. Or for weight, it's always *He might weigh as much as two hundred pounds* (virtually never ***many*** there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we talk about measurements, we use *much*. I would guess that this is because we're applying a countable measurement to an uncountable quantity. After all, angle is uncountable, as is distance, area and so on. Thus, you're not really talking about a *number* of degrees, but a quantity of angle that is represented by the number of degrees.

Telling when this is 'correct' and when it's a common 'error' is difficult, because errors are very common. Where talking about genuinely discrete objects, even abstract ones, it 'ought' to be *many* rather than *much*. However, people will use the 'wrong' one a lot, which really calls into question the idea that it's 'wrong'. However, if you're trying to avoid people who "know the rules" from correcting you, it's good to understand them as best as you can.

Answer (score 0):

‘As much as’ is correct because ‘degrees’ is a measurement,
and can involve decimals e.g. 40.5, 40.6 etc. and so it’s a ‘fluid’ concept we’re talking about here—temperature—it doesn’t always come in ‘units’, as it were.

But with ‘students’ for example, it *has to be* ‘as many as’ because you can’t have half a student, for example. It’s a *discrete* concept.

Comment: I'll go along with this, but I don't think "indivisible units" is the complete answer here. I see nothing wrong with a footballer, for example, saying *I'm sure we won't **lose** tomorrow's game, but I doubt we'll beat them by [as much as four goals*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+much+as+four+goals%22) And there's obviously no meaning to the concept of "fractional goal scores".

Comment: Well, to my mind, ‘as much as four goals’ does indeed seem incorrect. It’s akin to saying ‘The motion was contested by as much as 200 students’, which is surely wrong.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Good point. Also *she wouldn't give me so much as 50p* - you can't have decimals there either, but *many* would be even weirder than in the football example.

Comment: Well ‘so much as’ is a phrase of ‘so’, and means ‘even’, so in that case ‘so much as’ does indeed work.

Comment: @Inquisitive: I don't know what you mean by "incorrect". Do you mean that you're a native speaker and it sounds "off" to you, or that you've learned the "formal" rules of English *as a foreign language*, and it doesn't fit with your understanding of the rules? Many native speakers obviously *do* use the form we're talking about here, without necessarily thinking they're doing anything they "shouldn't".

Comment: I suppose I must to accept that "hours" are "divisible" *(It'll only take half an hour)*, so I take it you're unmoved by the fact that ***as much as two hours*** is several times more common than ***as many as two hours*** in Google Books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well yes, because time is a fluid concept, so ‘much’ is correct. It’s not like people or apples, for instance. And yes, it’s a rule that ‘many’ must be used for discrete ‘things’: if something does not necessarily come in discrete units, ‘much’ is correct.

Comment: Forty degrees are formed into one mass. Students not so much.

Comment: @FumbleFingers if you have CGEL, have a look at p. 354 on respecification of plural measure phrase nominals as as singular - in essence some measure phrases can be conceptualised as single entities, hence *as much as ten tons of plastic* etc (my example). It's not about whether you can have decimals, as your football example shows - more about whether we regard them as coalescing into one mass, as Orangesandlemons says.

Comment: @Minty: <Ahem> I'm a competent native speaker myself, so I don't need textbooks to tell me what's "correct". The point is I know perfectly well that my *as much as four goals* example is "valid", because it's a construction I and others would quite happily use. And from my perspective, "validity" derives from *what native speakers say*, not from "rules". But if a *learner* didn't already know that my example was valid, I don't see that they could figure it out by reasoning that those 4 goals are something we can "regard as coalescing into one mass".

Comment: @Fumblefingers: what Minty has said is another, better, way of putting what I have said and he/she is correct. Whether native speakers find it familiar or not does not matter. I am a native speaker, and ‘as much as four goals’ sounds wrong. ‘Harry and me went to the cinema’ sounds right to most native speakers but it does not change the *fact* that it is wrong. The fact that everyone speaks in a manner they *feel* is correct is why so many people make a rather embarrassing number of errors per day in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm utterly confused by the last three comments. I was agreeing with your original comment that "indivisible units" is not the complete answer, and suggesting that something more like a complete answer might be found in CGEL (which is absolutely not a book of prescriptive rules - it's a descriptive grammar). Obviously *by as much as four goals is correct*, as is my example *so much as 50p*, but the interesting question is why, given that the schoolbook rule dictates *many*.

Comment: @Inquisitive It's not another way of putting what you said at all - it contradicts what you say about *as much as four goals*, and explains why it is actually preferable in FF's context than your preferred *as many*. The same book also points out the fallacies in the reasoning that leads many people to say *Harry and me went to the cinema* must be incorrect. Like *much/many*, it's not that simple.

Comment: @Minty: I explained it that way to make the point that only a ‘fluid concept’ can be split in half ,’coalesced into one mass’, and so on. If you can ‘coalesce’ a group of things into a single entity, then you can also divide it into smaller entities. Tell me, how can four goals be considered as a mass?

Comment: @Minty: Also come to think of it, there is nothing wrong with half a penny e.g. ‘The manufacturing cost per product is half a penny.’ Half a goal, on the other hand, can never apply anywhere, not while retaining its meaning.

Comment: @Minty: I don't have access to CGEL p. 354, so I'm certainly not trying to disagree with anything they might say about the current issue. But it seems reasonable to say that both 1) "indivisibility" ***and*** 2) "multiple subcomponents treated as a single mass / entity" are relevant factors influencing "plurality". This affects the ***much / many*** choice, whereby it's reasonably straightforward to apply principle #2 there and recognize *I doubt it'll cost as much as 100 dollars* as "valid". But I think maybe it's not so obvious that principle does (or *should*) apply to my  "goals" example.

Comment: @Inquisitive For the sake of clarity, *fluid concept* doesn't normally mean what you seem to think it means - it refers to a concept that is flexible or changeable. I think the distinction you are drawing is really between quanities that are continuously variable and quantities that can only change by discrete steps.

Comment: Although units are countable by nature, when we regard them as a measure of some other quantity, it is that quantity that dictates whether we use much or many. For example, in football the score is measured in goals. Although goals are countable, when the focus is on the score as a whole, we prefer much - and usually our focus is on the score on the whole, so the construction with much is more natural.

Comment: One way to test whether this construction is available might go like this: A. How many muffins did you eat this morning? B: 10 A: that's too much / too many - here we have a choice because we are happy to let muffins be a measure of junk food / sweet food. Cf. A: How many people are coming tonight B: 80 A: that's too many. Here we don't have a choice. I think the reason is that although you can measure the size of a crowd or party by how many people are there, we don't like to treat people as mere units of measure. If something is going to be a unit...

Comment: ... it ought to be fungible, and we don't like to treat people as fungible. Most units of measure can be subdivided, so it's inevitable that in most cases where this construction is available, the noun serving as the unit will meet your subdivision test - but that's a red herring. What matters is just whether it is serving as a unit, which is why, in the rare case where a unit of measure is not subdivisible, it doesn't affect the availabilty of this construction.

Comment: @Inquisitive I think Orangesandlemons put it more succinctly when he said forty degrees are formed into one mass. Students not so much.

Answer (score -2):

'Degrees' is the plural form of the countable noun 'degree'.

So we should use 'many'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20many%20as):

***as many as***

idiom

—used to suggest that a number or amount is surprisingly large

// As many as 60 students competed for the prize.

// They lost by as many as 20 points.

The phrase with 'much' is possible but less preferable according to
Google Books Ngram Viewer:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=As+much+as+two%2C+as+many+as+two&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAs%20much%20as%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20many%20as%20two%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Points, unlike degrees, are (in most games) indivisible.